# Pleasure from taking a risk

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Is there a word that means the "*pleasure from taking a risk*"?

"*rush*" comes to mind but needs modifiers to make sense - thoughts?

Comment: The obvious two-word phrase is adrenaline rush.  Could you provide more context?

Comment: Sure, the feeling you get when:  I book a room at a cheap hostel and it turns out to be a 4 star experience.  I buy an unknown bottle of wine on sale and it becomes my new favorite.  Little risks that make you feel smart and happy.  All below are great too - thx

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes.  Seems like a legitimate on-topic question.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I thought so as well but as I'm new perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

After reading @bib s answer, I checked meanings for thrill. And you could use it, relating to meaning 6 from [here](http://www.finedictionary.com/thrill.html):

> thrill: an almost pleasurable sensation of fright

Comment: Exactly. That is exactly what I get when I do something scary that succeeds!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a word out there that would convey what you want without at least some modifiers.

But you can allude to risk-taking as a form of habit or addiction by using the colloquial terms "fix" or "kicks". If you're looking for something more formal, you may find the term "euphoria" quite descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

A term for someone who engages in the behavior you describe is **[thrill-seeker](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thrill-seeker)**

> a person who enjoys taking part in extreme sports and other activities involving physical risk

By extension, the activity is **thrill-seeking**.

Comment: But *thrill-seeker* and *thrill-seeking* describe the senser, not the sensation.

Comment: But it includes the sensation: thrill.